# How do I replace column names in a list with column values in the same row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7, replace

I've got a dataframe where 1 column lists Max value column names, Based on the names I'd like to replace them with those column values on the same row

| Max | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Column C | 200 | 500 | 800 |
| Column A | 600 | 700 | 1000 |

Expected output should be:

| Max | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 800 | 200 | 500 | 800 |
| 600 | 600 | 700 | 1000 |

I'm not sure what the best way to tackle this would be, any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is a sample list, the actual list is larger and more randomized

Comment: Are you using python 2.7?

Comment: What do you mean by _it gets more randomized_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you could try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Max': ['Column C', 'Column A'],
        'Column A': [200,600],
        'Column B': [500,700],
        'Column C': [800, 1000]
    }
)

df['Max'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x['Max']], axis=1)
```

Explanation: apply x[x['Max']] row wise to get the value of the column name